# MQOutput node issue

Tags: messagebroker

We are using WMB 7. Our message flow writes the output even though error is thrown.

MQOutput node throws error `MQ error code 2667. - Failed to put message`. However the message has been written to the output queue.

This issue is intermittent, i.e error is not thrown for all the messages. so far we have 2 occurences in our production environment.

For error handling, we have subflow.

The issue is that the output has been written to the queue though an error was thrown.

Comment: Do you mean BIP2667, not mqrc 2667? I don't think there is an MQ reason code 2667

Comment: sorry. It is BIP2667

Comment: Can you post the full BIP message. The third state parameter should be the MQRC code for why MQ thinks the put failed. Broker is sending the message down the failure terminal as MQ told it that the put failed.

Answer (score 0):

ERRORDMGIASXMLGROUPMSG2015-04-15 22:55:46.3869912667/build/S700_P/src/DataFlowEngine/ImbComputeNode.cpp489ImbComputeNode::evaluateComIbmComputeNodeIASXML_GROUP_MF#FCMComposite_1_3IASXML_GROUP_MF.AUDIT_INBIPmsgs32230Caught exception and rethrowing/build/S700_P/src/DataFlowEngine/ImbRdl/ImbRdlStatementGroup.cpp641SqlStatementGroup::executeComIbmComputeNodeIASXML_GROUP_MF#FCMComposite_1_3IASXML_GROUP_MF.AUDIT_INBIPmsgs32488Error detected, rethrowing5.IASXML_GROUP_MF_AUDIT_IN.Main544.45PROPAGATE TO TERMINAL 0 FINALIZE DEFAULT DELETE DEFAULT;/build/S700_P/src/DataFlowEngine/ImbComputeNode.cpp489ImbComputeNode::evaluateComIbmComputeNodeIASXML_GROUP_MF#FCMComposite_1_15IASXML_GROUP_MF.GROUPBIPmsgs32230Caught exception and rethrowing/build/S700_P/src/DataFlowEngine/ImbRdl/ImbRdlStatementGroup.cpp641SqlStatementGroup::executeComIbmComputeNodeIASXML_GROUP_MF#FCMComposite_1_15IASXML_GROUP_MF.GROUPBIPmsgs32488Error detected, rethrowing5.IASXML_GROUP_MF_GROUP.Main513.55THROW EXCEPTION CATALOG &apos;InvalidMessage&apos; MESSAGE 9999 VALUES( &apos;ErrorObject&apos;, Environment.Variable.ErrorObject);/build/S700_P/src/DataFlowEngine/ImbRdl/ImbRdlRoutine.cpp628SqlRoutine::invokeComIbmComputeNodeIASXML_GROUP_MF#FCMComposite_1_15IASXML_GROUP_MF.GROUPBIPmsgs32934Error occured in procedure5SetOutputMessage/build/S700_P/src/DataFlowEngine/ImbRdl/ImbRdlStatementGroup.cpp641SqlStatementGroup::executeComIbmComputeNodeIASXML_GROUP_MF#FCMComposite_1_15IASXML_GROUP_MF.GROUPBIPmsgs32488Error detected, rethrowing5.IASXML_GROUP_MF_GROUP.SetOutputMessage5202.45PROPAGATE TO TERMINAL 0 FINALIZE DEFAULT DELETE DEFAULT;/build/S700_P/src/DataFlowEngine/ImbComputeNode.cpp489ImbComputeNode::evaluateComIbmComputeNodeIASXML_GROUP_MF#FCMComposite_1_8IASXML_GROUP_MF.AUDIT_OUTBIPmsgs32230Caught exception and rethrowing/build/S700_P/src/DataFlowEngine/ImbRdl/ImbRdlStatementGroup.cpp641SqlStatementGroup::executeComIbmComputeNodeIASXML_GROUP_MF#FCMComposite_1_8IASXML_GROUP_MF.AUDIT_OUTBIPmsgs32488Error detected, rethrowing5.IASXML_GROUP_MF_AUDIT_OUT.Main510.45PROPAGATE TO TERMINAL 0 FINALIZE DEFAULT DELETE DEFAULT;/build/S700_P/src/DataFlowEngine/ImbMqOutputNode.cpp905ImbMqOutputNode::evaluateComIbmMQOutputNodeIASXML_GROUP_MF#FCMComposite_1_7IASXML_GROUP_MF.DMGCOMMONAUDITOUTBIPmsgs32230Caught exception and rethrowing/build/S700_P/src/DataFlowEngine/ImbMqOutputNode.cpp2186ImbMqOutputNode::putMessageComIbmMQOutputNodeIASXML_GROUP_MF#FCMComposite_1_7IASXML_GROUP_MF.DMGCOMMONAUDITOUTBIPmsgs32667Failed to put message2-15MQW10222003555DMGCOMMONAUDITOUT